# Play from beginning in Ableton Live 9

Tags: logic-pro, ableton, ableton-live

In Logic, I press enter twice and then space and I can play from the beginning of a track and resets my playhead.  How can I do this in Ableton Live 9 ? It always starts me at where my playhead is and it's annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Live, the spacebar plays from the start marker position. However, fn + left arrow (OSX) or Home (Win) should move the playhead to the beginning.

If you're using a MIDI controller for transport control, you can double-tap the "Stop" button which will return the marker to the beginning as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Ableton Live 9 all of the commands and functions can be easily custom mapped to any button of your choice.

If you look at the top right corner of the DAW directly above the MASTER volume column you'll see buttons labeled MIDI and KEY. Key being short for keyboard(computer) and Midi going to your choice of midi control.

Press one of those two buttons and start mapping. Say I want the session view record command to be assigned to the <kbd>+</kbd> key on my computer keyboard. I will click on the KEY button ... then click on the session record button ..... then hit the <kbd>+</kbd> key on my computer keyboard... then the KEY button once more to exit the keymaping edit mode.... its quite convient and super easy